# AjaxBehaviorEvent from f:ajax inside p:selectOneMenu is sometimes null

Tags: ajax, jsf, jsf-2, primefaces

I am currently observing a really weird behaviour in the server-side callback of an ajax call from a value change event. Basically, I have a list of p:selectOneMenus on my page and want to make some decisions based on what was selected where. This is the jsf:

```
        <p:outputLabel value="Provider:"/>
        <p:selectOneMenu id="bacc_ba_check" value="#{bean.baCheck}" style="width:20em" styleClass="bigDefaultEnabled" disabled="#{controller.readOnlyUser}">
            <f:selectItem itemLabel="none" itemValue=""/>
            <f:selectItems value="#{bean.baCheckStrings}" />
            <f:ajax listener="#{controller.providerChanged}" render="providerlist RPPPanel" onevent="reapplyDefaults" immediate="true"/>
        </p:selectOneMenu>
```

And this is the callback in the controller:

```
public void providerChanged(AjaxBehaviorEvent event) {

    // check for value
    if ("Someval".equalsIgnoreCase(...)) {

        this.setSomething(true);
    } else {
        this.setSomething(false);
    }
```

The confusing part is the following: The event is always NULL when I select something else than none from the selectOneMenu. If I reselect 'none' after having selected something else before, the event is correctly set. In the callback, I want to check what the source of the event is so I can set some defaults elsewhere. Does anyone have an idea what could cause this strange behaviour? I really need to know which component fired the event at all times, especially when someone select a non-null value in a dropdown.

Thanks for help or any hints.

(JSF 2.1.7 Mojarra with Primefaces 4.0)

Comment: Try: `p:ajax` instead of `f:ajax` (maybe f:ajax does not support all PF events?), try a newer JSF version, try a newer PF version, try debugging what IS sent from the client to the server, etc...etc...etc...

Comment: Indeed, when using PF components, technical recommendation is to use its own p:ajax instead of f:ajax.